# Can iCal merge Events of attendes into one shared event?

Tags: ical

When I want to see which Events other Users in iCal are attending through the delegates tab then I get the same entry multiple times for Events which my delegates and I have accepted. Is it possible to just show one event in some special color or else so I don't get a cluttered Month view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the moment it seems that this isn't possible. The logic behind using iCal with delegates is that you don't have the delegates tab activated all the time. Normally a delegate should only be looked at when it's needed. So the problem was more that I used the delegates tab in a wrong way ;)